# How to create logic in an enum

Tags: c#, enums

In C# I know we can't we assign objects to an Enum. The functionality I'm after is when an Enum is declared, it triggers off an event.

So instead of having

```
enum MyEnum
{
  string, int, etc
}
```

I could have

```
enum MyEnum
{
    classType1, classType2
}
```

This would then also allow the classes classType1/classType2 constructor to be called which could (for example) be useful for logging for when the enum is declared.

Another way of presenting my issue could be

```
enum MyEnum
{
   string1
      {
          //logic
      },
   string2
      {
          //logic
      }
}
```

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Factories (Factory Pattern)

Comment: Neither `enum` is anywhere near valid or possible.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Fine - if you want to put that as an answer then I can mark it as such.

Comment: @Grumbler85 I know the Factory Pattern but didn't think of 'combining it' with an enum, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @DaveRook perhaps you should explain what the reason behind what you are trying to do is?

Comment: @DaveRook define *assigned*? From your examples you are referring to how an enum is *declared*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `enum` you can use a `static class` with static properties, it can be used same as an `enum` but you can write code inside getter and setter.

Comment: True, it's a nice idea to get round this issue and will suffice. Thank you.

Comment: Or you could use an immutable instance implementation http://stackoverflow.com/a/12671340/659190

Answer (score 1):

U could use `properties` instead of `enum` (then u can write ur own logic which will be called after/before assigning the variable). The `enum` structure should be used to create flags-like stuff.

```
private string _myVar;
public string MyVar
{
   get { return _myVar; }
   set
   {
      // logic 1 here
      _myVar = value;
      // logic 2 here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No work around as, I think, your expectation does not match the language. For example consider what would happen with:

```
if (myEnumValue == MyEnum.classType1)
```

Your question implies that on the right a class of 'classType1' would be instantiated for the equality test and then the result would depend on that types implementation of equality. This is confusing when the item on the left is an enum ... but with your assumption it is an object of type 'classType1' which implies that both the left and right are temporary objects.

You can see that this could not work.

But ... what I think your really after is a factory to create objects from an enum. Whole other question that raised other questions (sorry). An enum like this implies a state ... so if you have a state why does that state need an enum? A big question in itself, check out the state pattern.

Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is a Value type based on an `Int##` type. So this is the same as asking: can I get some logic into the assignment of `int i = 7;` and the direct answer is No.

Neither can you base an `enum` on anything other than an integer type.

But your requirement seems to be with tracking instances.  That's easy with properties. But you can only do it for a specific property, not build it into the Type.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are barely integers with comprehensive labels. As far as I know, what you are looking for cannot be done using enums.

However, and as stated by @Grumbler85,  this behavior can be simulated using factories. 
A factory is a special type of object that are used to create instances of other objects.

The easiest way to implement a factory is using a switch statement but other ways exists (reflection for example). Here's a simple example of what you are looking for:

```
Class A
{
   ...
}

Class B
{
   ... 
}

enum eKnownTypes
{
     A,
     B
}

Class Factory
{
    /* 
         Implement Singleton here
         ....
    */
    public object CreateInstance(eKnownTypes t)
    {
         /*
               Raise any event needed here
               ...
         */
         switch (t):
         {
              case eKnownTypes.A: return new A(); break;
              case eKnownTypes.B: return new B(); break;
         }          
         return null;
    }

}

/* 
         Set Event Handlers here
         Factory.Instance.CustomEvent += new EventHandler ... 
         ....
*/
A objectA = Factory.Instance.CreateInstance(eKnownTypes.A) as A;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an enum, but you could do

```
public struct MyType
{
    public const int OneValue = 1;
    public const int TwoValue = 2;

    private static readonly MyType one = new MyType(OneValue);
    private static readonly MyType two = new MyType(TwoValue); 

    private readonly value int;

    private MyType(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static One
    {
        get { return this.one; }
    }

    public static Two
    {
        get { return this.two; }
    }

    public static implicit operator int(MyType source)
    {
        return source.value;
    }
}
```

To give you a class that behaves like an enum but is fully extendable.

for instance, you can do

```
var myType = MyType.One;

switch (myType)
{
   case MyType.OneValue:
       ...

   case MyType.TwoValue:
       ...

   default:
       ...
}
```

The instances are immutable and can be accuarately tested for equality using the implemenation inhereted from `object`, i.e. reference quality.